# Map Matching (snap GPS points road) in ArcGIS (REST API)?

Tags: arcgis-android, map-matching

Does ArcGIS have Map Matching function? (In Google Maps Services it's called "Snap to roads" - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)

I checked next link, but didn't find anything: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/get-started-with-the-services-directory.htm

What is Map Matching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching

Example:

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information.

Comment: @user155 Welcome to GIS Stackexchange. I believe you are getting downvoted for a few reasons. One is that is seems you did not do any research of your own before submitting the question, or at least that is not clear from your question. What have you already tried? What is ArcGIS for Android? Also there is very little information in your question. This is a Q&A site, but we are not here to do your work for you, we are here to assist you in finding the right answer.

Comment: @user155 This should be clear in your question. We don't know what you did before asking unless you make it clear in the original question. You can edit your question using the edit button underneath the question.

Comment: Link-only answers are deleted as unhelpful. Link-only questions are downvoted for being unclear. All the information you have provided in comments should be in the question body, along with a complete description of what you have tried.

Comment: @Vince I've updated the question

Comment: It's still a link-only question.

Comment: There is nothing I'm aware of in the Mobile space (iOS, Android, etc) The only tools I can think of are the [conflation tools](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/an-overview-of-the-conflation-toolset.htm). These are Desktop tools, although you could probably publish them to work in a service. That said, do a search across GIS.SE on that topic to see if there is anything helpful:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=Conflation

Comment: @Vince I thought I can't add images (only links), anyway I've updated the question again and I believe users can understand what I want

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ArcGIS (maybe a plugin?) but it's not as easy at it seems. Usually, you should use an external service dedicated to that problem, as you need road data prepared in a specific form to do it efficiently. That probably was what you wanted to say? You are looking for a plugin that can match a set of points in one of your layer? You should reformulate your question then.

For the service itself, there is an open source service called OSRM (you can build your own server with it, or more simply use their demo server) to do that:
[Documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/?language=cURL#match-service)

Here is an example of how to use it:
[Example](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/2949)

Comment: I know about OSRM, for that you need your own server (very powerful for all world). Isn't **ArcGIS** should be similar to **Google Map's** services?. Google Maps has such function https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap ArcGIS doesn't?

Comment: As I said, you can use their demo server if you don't have too much requests. Sorry I don't know much about ArcGIS, I usually stick with QGIS and PostGIS

Comment: I mean. I'm here not for having fun. Demo server is just a toy which stops working after a couple of requests

Comment: Yet you want to do world map matching in a desktop app ^^. I don't know what volume you want to manipulate, but if it's more than a few trips (5000 requests/minutes shared for everybody, no time limit, ok for most of simple usages), you should consider either build your own servers (you can build a server for just a country), or see directly with a specialized company (ESRI, Mapbox, Google,...) to buy a specific service, or maybe you should ask ESRI directly to see if it's included in your licence (I'm guessing that was the sense of your question?)

Comment: And of course I understand that we have to pay for a specific plan to use such service

Comment: My bad too, when you said ArcGIS, I just assumed that you used the desktop app, displayed a few trip and wanted to match them for some reason. But of course if you are building an android app, it's a whole different story... Please give some context next time to avoid such misunderstanding :)

Comment: My questions were edited by other users as well, they edited it to "for Desktop" :) but, yes, REST API isn't limited to any sub-products (mobile or desktop), it can be used from anything we want